# Unable to generate/call defined name formula based on selected list value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-2010, vlookup

i am trying to create a dynamic dashboard for classes attendance,

as can be seen in the attached image example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozcpo.jpg)

I have defined names A,B,C respectively to classes tables ClassA, ClassB and ClassC. I have a list class in G8, on which selecting value i am trying to call the name function A/B/C and fill in cells F13:H17 which i am not yet successful.

could you help on how I can achieve this.

when i do =A in F13 directly and select from the suggestion the table data is retrieved, but when I enter =G8 in F13 it is only displaying A/B/C instead of retrieving the named cells.

Answer (score 2):

When you type `=A`, you are using `=A` (including the equal sign). When you refer to it like `=G8`, you are only capturing the letter `A`, without the equal sign, so it will not be recognized as a formula.

To use the contents of a cell as the reference in a formula, use `INDIRECT`.

Instead of

```
=G8
```

try

```
=INDIRECT(G8)
```